# Highchart - yAxis - 1,000 should be displayed like 1000

Tags: highcharts

I can't find the settings for my problem in the Highchart API.

I've cerated an example on jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qErT2/

How can I swap 1,000 into 1000 ??

```
Greetings
```

Answer (score 2):

HighChart number format is the same like [PHP NUMBER FORMATS](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

you can use this format any where

**for tooltip**

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function () 
    {
        return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' + this.x + ' - <b>' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0,'',''); + '</b>';
    }
}
```

**for  yAxis**

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
        formatter: function () {
            return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.value, 0,'','');
        }
    }
},
```

[YOUR EXAMPLE MODIFIED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qErT2/1/) (tooltip)

AND [UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qErT2/3/) (tooltip and yAxis labels)

Comment: Thank you for your help. But my problem is the yAxis - directly the xAxis. In your example again the values are displayed like 1,000   2,000 and so on. This is my problem

Comment: review my updated answer and updated demo, you can use this formatter over any element of highCharts

Answer (score 1):

Take look at lang options http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang and obviously you can use Highcharts.numberFormat() http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.numberFormat() which can be used in tooltip formater / label formatter to display numbers as you need.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter